# Unable to install Sql Server 2014 (Windows Update issue)

Tags: sql, installation, sql-server-2014

Installing Sql Server 2014 on Windows 7. I have previously had Sql Server 2013, 2014, 2016 installed on this machine successfully. A system crash forced a reinstall. First I uninstalled all old versions. Removed all files and folders. Cleaned the registry.

Now when I attempt a fresh install I repeatedly run into this issue related to Windows Update. I've tried a few suggested fixes, nothing as worked. Looking for real solutions. This is the error message that blocks the installation:

[image: The error message]

Comment: Have you checked whether the files are at the location that the setup is looking at? Are you running as Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by various reasons, but for further investigation, try to read your log message (In the case you have not already tried that). I hope you will find some more information, how to fix this.